# Mathematica literature

Tags: reference-request

Before you start saying that this is duplicate, I had searched and read other similar questions, but none of them seem to have answer of my question.

I am very, very good in C, C++, Matlab. I have decided to learn Mathematica. I am looking for book or some literature from which I could start learning it (I learn best from books). This is my question: What book should I use, when I have good programming background and I am really good in mathematics?

In all other answers I found books that are "great" but they all require basic knowledge of Mathematica, or books that totally start from the scratch(no programming or mathematical knowledge required, like Stephen Wolfram's).

I am electrical engineer and I would really like to find some book that is best for my profile.

Comment: What about: http://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/

Comment: Have you seen this topic: [Learn Mathematica (Wolfram) Language in one day](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/138366/5478)?

Comment: [Leonid Shifrin's book](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/) (free).

Comment: Please say what previous questions you have read, what books you have considered etc. Right now, I don't really understand what it is you're not satisfied with, among the advice that already exists in other places. My go to suggestions are [Power Programming with Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16485/731) and Mathematica Cookbook. Since Mathematica is very different from the other languages that you know, you also need to solve lots of problems to understand the paradigms in Mathematica. This site is a good source of problems and solutions.

Comment: tomd I read that answer, but as you can see in introduction of the book, the author says that book's aim is to give understanding of Mathematica to people that already use it (I don't know syntax at all).

Kuba These are certainly interesting books and I will let you know what I think about them after reading/researching a littlebit.

C.E. I know that is different and I think I made clear what confuses me. I considered every book that is on Wolfram website. The problem is I don't want to read books that explain loops and programming techniques. I am interested in learning funct. and syntax

Comment: @fzy I wrote something for some chemists a bit ago which touches on a lot of useful stuff for myself: https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1/MathematicaBasics.nb. It might help you.

Comment: This question might be a better fit, in terms of content, for community.wolfram.com.

Comment: @fzy Books on Mathematica are going to spend maybe one page on loops, which you will need to read in order to understand how they are different from loops in other languages. Loops are rarely used in Mathematica. The programming techniques you have learned in those other languages will also have a limited applicability, since they are procedural languages and Mathematica uses a "functional symbolic language". Anyway, you will find that neither of the books I mentioned are written for people without programming experience.